# How can I back-fill all leading null values from a DataFrame column with the first non-null value of a different column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a DataFrame, like in the picture below, which details a change-history of sorts for multiple groups.

Each row has:

1. An old value (that which the value was changed from)
2. A new value (that which the value was changed to)
3. A Date
4. A Group Name

For example: { Group: 'A', Date: '2021-01-01', Old_value: 7, New_value: 9}
would represent a case where Group A, on 2021-01-01, had its value changed from 7 to 9.

I need to determine, from the first old/new value combination, what the value was prior to that **initial** change per group.

For example a dataset which looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydChU.png)

Should look like this after the desired transformation:

[Desired Transformation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmafH.png)

Please let me know if there's anything else you need me to provide to help me!

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide data here ... not in form of a picture ... also share your efforts to get this result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.